# Make Rails autoloading/reloading follow dynamic includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming

### Context

I want to add some admin specific code to all models via concerns that are automatically included. I'm using the naming convention `MyModel` => `MyModelAdmin` and they're in the standard Rails directory `app/models/concerns/my_model_admin.rb`. Then I can glob over all of them and do `MyModel.include(MyModelAdmin)`.

### Issue

Dynamic includes work fine, but when changing the concern in development Rails doesn't reload it properly. In fact the concern seems to get removed.

### Reproduction

app/models/my_model.rb

```
class MyModel
end
```

app/models/concerns/my_model_admin.rb

```
module MyModelAdmin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def say
    "moo"
  end
end
```

config/initializers/.rb

```
MyModel.include(MyModelAdmin)
```

So far so good, `MyModel.new.say == "moo"`.
But now change say to "baa" and you get `NoMethodError undefined method 'say'`.

### Notes

I tried a number of things that didn't help:

- `require_dependency`
- `Model.class_eval "include ModelAdministration"`
- `config.autoload_paths`
- Using another explicit concern in `ApplicationModel` with an `included` hook that includes the specific concern in each model.
- `ActiveSupport.on_load` only triggered on Base not each model.

Does this mean Rails can only autoload using static scope? I guess Rails sees the concern change, knows the model has it included, reloads the model but the static model definition doesn't have the include so the concern goes missing and stops being tracked. Is there a way to force Rails to track dynamically included modules?

Comment: You're saying Rails sees the concern change so it reloads the including model? How come, shouldn't it only reload the concern itself (as that is the class that was changed?)

Comment: I'm tempted to say that this is a Rails 3 issue and wouldn't happen on Rails 4+ but I haven't really checked it

Comment: @Joel_Blum I'm using Rails 5, and I don't really know what's happening or why the model is loosing the concern after reload.